# Drag and Drop between Outlook and Add-in Pane

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to drag an attachment or e-mail to an Outlook Web-Addin.
The add-in is available to either Outlook 365 (Web) or the main client

My assumption is no - as it is a sandboxed boundary, but I have heard about people running applications in the system tray to intercept the mouse drag event?

Is this viable? are there any security risks with this approach?

Thank you
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System tray interception is not a viable solution, not only because of security concerns, but because of deployment reasons. Add-ins functionality and entry points should be entirely described by their manifest files and should not require the user to install any background process.

As to drag-and-drop support in general, currently drag-and-drop to the sandbox is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

After they have updated the addin pane to use the edge based browser engine, you can have support for drag and drop. It has the following outlook requirements

- Office 365, version 16.0.11629 will be the next Office 365 monthly update.
- Windows 10, version 1903 will be released in May, 2019.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? In a quick demo the ondrop handler is not even remotely fired neither on the taskpane nor in a custom dialog. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a sample code or any documentation link you can provide for this @sjkp??